# Continuous object creation in pygame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

Okay, so I've researched this topic a bit. I'm creating a game in Python's Pygame, a replica of the famous "Raiden 2". My game loop is fairly similar to those I've seen around. What I'm trying to do is have the constructor create a bullet object (with my Bullet class) while the space bar is being held. However, the following code only creates a single bullet per keypress. Holding the button does nothing, just creates a single bullet.

```
while game.play is True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                b = Bullet(x, y)
                bullet_group.add(b)

    bullet_group.draw(screen)
```

Not sure where to go from here. Any help is welcome and appreciated.

Comment: So you want to create several bullets each keypress?

Comment: I think you are looking for https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.set_repeat

Comment: You are only looking at `KEYDOWN` event, so you only get the event once per key press.  For real time games like this I like to use, `pygame.key.get_pressed()`

Comment: @cmd Hey, it works! Thanks for helping me out. I didn't know KEYDOWN didn't work for multiple object creation...

Comment: @Minighost Don't forget to accept an answer to complete the question/answer process ... (the "V" on the left side of the answer turning green on click signalizing the answer was accepted)

Comment: @Minighost Accepting an answer gives you +2 reputation points :) and saves time of others who check out not yet answered questions ready to help to get the question/answer cycle completed by providing an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work as you expect it:

```
addBullets = False
while game.play is True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                addBullets = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                addBullets = False

    if addBullets: 
        b = Bullet(x, y)
        bullet_group.add(b)

    bullet_group.draw(screen)
```

You move the creation of bullets out of the handling of events and set there only a "flag" which is taken back if the key is released stopping creation of bullets.

And ... as mentioned in the comment by `jsbueno` this will work too:

> ```
> while game.play is True:
>     for event in pygame.event.get():
>        pass # do something with events
>     if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_SPACE]: 
>         b = Bullet(x, y)
>         bullet_group.add(b)
> ```

Comment: Cool. Another option is to use `pygame.key,get_pressed()[pygame.K_SPACE]` to know if a given key (in this case, space) is pressed at the time of the function call.

Comment: Woah so many options... I think I'll stick with @jsbueno 's method of using get_pressed(). Seems to work consistently with my code. Thanks so much you guys!

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answer is lacking an important detail. You most likely don't want to fire a bullet every frame, so you need to have some kind of timer. The simplest way is to count the frames, but then the game would be frame rate bound (better don't do it in this way).

```
firing = False
bullet_timer = 0

while game.play:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game.play = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                firing = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                firing = False

    if bullet_timer > 0:
        bullet_timer -= 1
    elif firing:  # Timer is less than 0 and we're firing.
        bullet = Bullet()
        bullet_group.add(bullet)
        bullet_timer = 10   # Reset timer to 10 frames.
```

The frame rate independent variant is to use the time that `pygame.Clock.tick` returns (the time that has passed since it was called the last time) and subtract it from the timer variable. If the timer is `<= 0` we're ready to fire.

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
firing = False
bullet_timer = 0

while game.play:
    # `dt` is the passed time since the last tick in seconds.
    dt = clock.tick(30) / 1000

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                firing = True
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                firing = False

    if bullet_timer > 0:
        bullet_timer -= dt
    elif firing:  # Timer is below 0 and we're firing.
        bullet = Bullet()
        bullet_group.add(bullet)
        bullet_timer = .5  # Reset timer to a half second.
```